# Github commits are shown as cloned versions of myself

Tags: github, git-commit, help-authoring

So I recently decided to reset my computer to factory settings and cloned the repository via ssh and https and get multiple versions of myself authoring /commits. I want my github pushes to only shown one version of myself.

I tried google and multiple ways of cloning the repository to see if it's an issue recognizing my identity but have been getting a new version authoring/commit when I make a new clone.

Comment: Every git commit has an author-name and author-email associated (set by gitconfig at the time of committing). That's all there is to "identity" in git. (+ signatures but i assume this question is not about signatures).
the author information is immutable in every commit, so the repository you have cloned is the same that you pushed before resetting your machine.
I dont know what you mean by "multiple versions of myself". are you using some kind of git UI that does some github-account or gravatar magic?